# XMLHttpRequest GET gets cancelled when form is submitted on a page

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, xmlhttprequest

I have a page where onclick of a button an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest is fired. Also, a particular form is submitted for the click.

So, my code looks like :

```
<a href="fireRequest(); submitForm(); return false;">LINK</a>
```

THe problem is, the request gets cancelled when the form is submit. When I remove the submitForm() call, the request works fine. Is there a way to still complete the request before submitting the form? I can make the request synchronous but it does not suit my application.

Comment: making the XMLHttpRequest synchronous seems to be the solution, why can't you use that?

Comment: Call `submitForm` in the callback function of the XHR.

Comment: Actually, the JS file is provided as a plugin to third party host sites. Making it synchronous will make them dependent on the completion of my request, which I don't want to do. If my server becomes slow or unresponsive sometime, it will affect the host site. If there is absolutely no other way to do this, I don't mind making it synchronous. For the same reason, I can't make the submitForm() call in the callback function.